# Regex: Find word but not allow repetition

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following test and i want to extract all codes following *HAB:* and they must have *REST* in front but can have other words in between:

> REST gfdjj REST HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-01 CLUE HAB: 234-543 REST tt HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-02 CLUE ytr HAB: 34829-5467 REST HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-03 REST REST REST HAB: 54783-04 REST HA: 837483 REST dfhjdf REST 347845-34 REST rehs HAB: 45923 REST HAB: REST sdfdgdsd HAB: 456734

https://regex101.com/r/4inYr4/3

I tried `(REST.*?) *(HAB:) (.*?)( |$)` but it also returns the many redundant *REST*s,

`(REST) *(HAB:) (.*?)( |$)` but it doesn't return the second code,

and `(REST(?!.*REST).*?) *(HAB:) (.*?)( |$)` but it only returns the last one.

I need some kind of conditional regex that only allows other words than *REST* to be inbetween *REST* and *HAB:*, which I expected the last one to do?

EDIT:

I want to extract:

1. REST 75RF-3729-70D-01
2. REST 75RF-3729-70D-02
3. REST 75RF-3729-70D-03
4. REST 54783-04
5. REST 45923

EDIT 2:

I need the REST part, i updated the question and added some *CLUE*s to emphasize that i need *REST*

I use Python 2.7

EDIT 3:

I also need to find *REST* 456734 in:

> REST HAB: REST sdfdgdsd HAB: 456734

Comment: What are you trying to match from your sample?

Comment: In your regex101 test, your test string does not include the -01 to -04 suffixes on the codes. When I put those on and use your second regex it returns all 3 codes 75RF-3729-70D-01, 75RF-3729-70D-03 and 54783-04

Comment: Do you need the `REST` part? Also, what tool/language are you using?

Comment: Try [`(REST).*? *HAB: (\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/1), see [also this Python demo](http://rextester.com/NXXHI34712).

Comment: But 45923 isn't followed by HAB.

Comment: Sorry, i meant codes FOLLOWING _HAB:_

Comment: Have you tried @WiktorStribiżew 's code?

Comment: Yes, thanks, i added EDIT 3, because it worked for the problem that i described but doesn't completely achieve what i wanted

Comment: Then try [`(REST).*? *HAB: (?=\S*\d)(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/2) to enforce at least one digit in the second group.

Comment: Or [`(REST).*?HAB:\s*([^\s\d]*\d\S*)`](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/3)

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement to match text from `REST` till `HAB:` excluding `REST` is not actually helpful, it won't affect matching much, however, the text after `HAB:` cannot be `REST`, as it will prevent valid matches.

You may use

```
(REST).*?HAB:\s*(?!REST(?!\S))(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/4)

**Details**

- `(REST)` - Group 1: a `REST` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `HAB:` - a `HAB:` literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?!REST(?!\S))` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `REST` followed with whitespace or end of string
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: any 1+ non-whitespace chars.

[Python code demo](http://rextester.com/JXK75503):

```
import re
rx = r"(REST).*?HAB:\s*(?!REST(?!\S))(\S+)"
s = """REST gfdjj REST HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-01 CLUE HAB: 234-543 REST tt HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-02 CLUE ytr HAB: 34829-5467 REST HAB: 75RF-3729-70D-03 REST REST REST HAB: 54783-04 REST HA: 837483 REST dfhjdf REST 347845-34 REST rehs HAB: 45923\nREST HAB: REST sdfdgdsd HAB: 456734"""
res = ["{} {}".format(x.group(1),x.group(2)) for x in re.finditer(rx, s)]
print(res)
# => ['REST 75RF-3729-70D-01', 'REST 75RF-3729-70D-02', 'REST 75RF-3729-70D-03', 
#    'REST 54783-04', 'REST 45923', 'REST 456734']
```

Comment: He uses `python 2.7`, I dont think ur code works there. But in `python 3` it works fine.

Comment: @ShashankSingh [The link](http://rextester.com/JXK75503) proves it does.

Comment: My bad I tried it on `python 2.6`, Sorry. It does work.

Comment: is it possible to enforce that there are no RESTs captured at all, not just immediately to the right?

Comment: @TobSta Probably you want [`r"(REST)(?:(?!REST).)*?HAB:\s*(?!REST(?!\S))(\S+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/kN7hvR/5)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this output?

```
REST 75RF-3729-70D-01
REST 75RF-3729-70D-02
REST 75RF-3729-70D-03
REST 54783-04
REST 45923
REST 456734
REST 456734
```

You may try this pattern.

```
.*?(REST\s)(?:(?:(?!REST|HAB).)*HAB\:\s*)(\b(?:(?!REST)[-\w])+\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4inYr4/4)

What you want to extract are captured pairwise in capture group 1, 2